# Alternative for "connect by" Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Anyone be able to give me some script that does the same as the below but not using "connect by"? The code works well, but I cannot use connect by in the BI publisher.

```
select to_char(to_date('2022-05-01') + (level -1),'YYYY-MM-DD') as read_date 
from dual 
connect by to_date('2022-05-01') + (level -1) <= to_date('2022-05-05')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CONNECT BY` is Oracle's propriatary and concise way to write a recursive query. You can replace it with a standard SQL compliant recursive query that has been supported by Oracle since 2002.

```
with read_dates(read_date) as
(
  select date '2022-05-01' from dual
  union all
  select read_date + interval '1' day from read_dates
  where read_date < date '2022-05-05'
)
select to_char(read_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
from read_dates;
```

Two remarks:

- Your own code is vulnarable, because it uses an implicit string to date conversion (`to_date('2022-05-01')`) that relies on session date settings and can thus fail miserably.
- It is rare that we select dates as strings (`to_char(..., 'YYYY-MM-DD')`), because we usually want our app to know that we are selecting dates.

Comment: If the OP is using Oracle 11g then this code will not work as there are bugs in the  handling of dates in recursive queries. It can be fixed by generating a numeric offset and adding it to the start date [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fPzFE0h2).

Comment: @MT0: Thank you for pointing this out. and for offering a workaround, too. I had completely forgotton about those issues so long time ago.